# How to use(or convert) this NATIVE BLE DFU library for Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy, nrf51

I'm making app with using Xamarin.forms (PCL project).

I'm making app like FITBIT and its wearable device.

I'm using nrf51822 MCU from Nordic.
Someone has done lots of work for syncing with ble device for Xamarin.Forms and fortunately it's working great.

Now, I need to use DFU OTA library to support firmware-update for users.
Nordic provided great examples and source code.

dfu lib for iOS : https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/IOS-DFU-Library

full project(iOS) : https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/IOS-nRF-Toolbox

dfu lib for Android : https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-DFU-Library

And How can I convert this library for using it on Xamarin?
What documents or technique should I look? 
Any tips will help me. (It might be lots of pain?)

Thanks.

Nordic says they didn't even start to look Xamarin, So there are only three guys(including me) are looking for these binding project.

discusion here : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/214516

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read this documentation Xamarin.Android supports the use of native libraries via the standard PInvoke mechanism. You can also bundle additional native libraries which are not part of the OS into your .apk.

Android.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/using_native_libraries/

the same for 
iOS.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/native_interop/

Regards. I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38943806/next-step-to-make-binding-for-embedded-framework-for-xamarin-ios . Could you help me little bit again? Thanks.