# Next step to Make Binding for embedded framework for Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: xamarin, binding, frameworks, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to use Native iOS framework from BLE chip bender(nordic) on Xamarin iOS.
this framework (iOS Native - swift) : https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/IOS-DFU-Library/tree/master/documentation

1. I made a fat framework with those iOS library. And I looked this doc.
   https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/embedded_frameworks/
2. I imported it as Native framework on Xamarin.iOS project. And I want to use it.

Below code is from that I used when i'm making iOS native app. I will have to use it on Xamarin.

(part of my app's code(objc base) - using that library )

```
DFUServiceInitiator *initiator = [[DFUServiceInitiator alloc] initWithCentralManager: [DeviceManager getInstance].central target:[DeviceManager getInstance].connectedPeripheral];
[initiator withFirmwareFile:nil];
initiator.forceDfu = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"dfu_force_dfu"] boolValue];
initiator.packetReceiptNotificationParameter = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"dfu_number_of_packets"] intValue];
initiator.logger = self;
initiator.delegate = self;
initiator.progressDelegate = self;
// initiator.peripheralSelector = ... // the default selector is used

DFUServiceController *controller = [initiator start];
```

3. So in Xamarin.iOS project. 
   I will use framework that I just imported. And I tried declaring 'DFUServiceInitiator' class. But nothing works but gives 'could not be found' error. Maybe there is many things left I have to do. Yes, this can't be that easy.

Next step is 'binding(wrapping) framework to c#'? Could you guide little bit please?

Is this document I should look next?
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/native_interop/

or this?
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/walkthrough/

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not simply include a Objective-C or Swift library in you Xamarin project and use it by copying Objective-C or Swif code. You need to create a binding project to create wrapping-classes to get a .NET-api. And that is where Xamarin binding projects come into play.

So you should go with https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/walkthrough/ and learn about how to build bindings for native libraries. Depending on the library it isn't that hard.

Comment: Hi tequila. Thank for answering my question. According to that doc's OVERVIEW, He says "In the first and second scenario there will already be a precompiled CocoaTouch Static Library so in this article we will focus on the third scenario." and my scenario is second "As a precompiled Framework". Then I will have to jump to middle of doc, "Create a Xamarin.iOS Binding Project", Is that correct?

Comment: I just used Objective Sharpie to make a wrapper class. But when I build project, it gives error that says "No API definition file specified". What is that mean?

Comment: I made new project and I passed that part. and I'm fixing errors.

Comment: FInally, I success to build Xamarin library project. Now I will try to use it in my project

Comment: Does Xamarin not support Swift framework?? if so, I'm screwed?

Comment: Unfortunately no support for Swift at the moment.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I'll look objc-swift bridge something

Comment: @BrightLee Hey, I found a lot of your activities regarding the DFU libraries on Stackoverflow and in Nordic's DevZone. I'm trying to accomplish the same thing and wanted to check back if you got any further. Unfortunately, most of the discussions lead to a dead end.

Comment: @FrozenTarzan I gave up using native SDK binding thing. But thankfully, there was a guy who wrote the code for nordic DFU in C#. I used it and it has worked great.

Comment: @BrightLee I see, do you refer to the [Arendi-BLE-Library](https://www.arendi.ch/produkte/arendi-ble-library/) posted by Adrian Eggenberger in the [here in the Nordic DevZone](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/15450/dfu-in-ios-xamarin/130499#130499)?